# PHP: convert all UTF-8 characters to HTML entities

Tags: php, utf-8

I am attempting to use `mb_encode_numericentity()` to convert all special UTF-8 characters into HTML entities. The following code converts some characters, like ㋡, but not others, like .

```
echo encodespecial('㋡ ヅ Hello World   ');

function encodespecial($str)
{
    $convmap = array(0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff);
    
    return mb_encode_numericentity($str, $convmap, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Comment: It would probably be more productive to solve the problem to which this is the proposed solution.

Comment: Your interval end simply doesn't go far enough. `` is `0xf09d91a5` in UTF-8 encoding - but you are stopping at `0xffff`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, based on CBroe's explanation:

```
echo encodespecial('㋡ ヅ Hello World    this is a test....');
function encodespecial($str) {
    $convmap = array(0x80, 0xfffffff, 0, 0xfffffff);
    return mb_encode_numericentity($str, $convmap, 'UTF-8');
}
```